# Feature Survey - What would you want in a resume theme?

Tags: theme-development, customization

I've been toying with the idea of developing a custom resume/portfolio theme for some time ... but just haven't gotten around to it.  Lately, though, I've fallen in love with a few new site designs and feel that it's time we had a truly interactive and dynamic theme to power resumes and portfolios with WordPress.

So here it is, your opportunity to participate in a WP crowdsourcing project:

What features would you *most* like to see in a resume/portfolio theme for WordPress and why?

Comment: This is marked as a community wiki so we can cultivate a list of features/functionality ideas for a highly useful theme.  One feature/concept per answer please ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to see dynamically expanding detail boxes, so you can provide optionally more details on specific areas of experience (such as a code snippet, or more complicated project information) should the interested party wish for more. That way you keep it simple and clean yet show them there is more under the hood should they wish to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I like the way that Elegant Themes did their Resume Theme, but I have a few mods I'd like to see done to it.

- Project details (with gallery etc) in a lightbox
- Contact form
- Post feed

Answer (score 1):

In a resume site, I'd like to see the option to write up my experience both in functional terms and in chronological terms. I get to choose.  I don't want it to be strictly chronological, as I may want to draw on some earlier life experience when looking for my next job or new clients.